# React Navigation 5.x navigation transition animation based on param

Tags: reactjs, react-native, animation, react-navigation

Is it possible to enable/disable the navigation transition animation based on a specifically passed param?

```
navigation.navigate('SomeScreen', {
          data: someData,
          withAnimation: true,
        });
```

In the example above, the `withAnimation` param is set to `true`, so I want the animation (`forRevealFromBottomAndroid`) set here to be active:

```
<Stack.Screen
        name="SomeScreen"
        component={SomeScreen}
        options={{
          headerLeft: null,
          headerShown: false,
          cardStyleInterpolator:
            CardStyleInterpolators.forRevealFromBottomAndroid,
        }}
      />
```

Answer (score 8):

Yes **it's possible**. You can achieve it this way:

In your navigator:

```
<Stack.Screen
        name="SomeScreen"
        component={SomeScreen}
        options={({route: {params}}) => ({
          headerLeft: null,
          headerShown: false,
          cardStyleInterpolator: params?.withAnimation
              ? CardStyleInterpolators.forHorizontalIOS
              : CardStyleInterpolators.forNoAnimation,
        })}
/>
```

Where you navigate:

```
navigation.navigate('SomeScreen', {
    data: someData,
    withAnimation: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this way:

```
let animation = false;
cardStyleInterpolator: animation ? CardStyleInterpolators.forNoAnimation : CardStyleInterpolators.forHorizontalIOS
```